# Probability Homework Question - Use Product Rule to count Number of Permutations?

Tags: probability

Below is a homework question I have as part of an assignment. I know what I'm suppose to do such as use product rule to prove the number of permutations that define Events A and B but I'm not sure how to start or finish it.  Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks :)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find $\rm P(A)$ and $\rm P(B)$ and also $\rm P(A.B)$ then show that $\rm P(A)P(B)=P(A.B)$
If you're having problem finding those try them for a while and if you fail try to decipher these:

**Spoiler:Hint**

> $${\rm P(A)}=\frac{{}^{n}{\rm C}_2(n-2)!}{n!}=\frac{n(n-1)}{2n(n-1)}=\frac12$$

**Spoiler:Hint**

> $${\rm P(B)}=\frac{{}^{n}{\rm C}_32!(n-3)!}{n!}=\frac{2n(n-1)(n-2)}{6n(n-1)(n-2)}=\frac13$$

**Spoiler:Hint**

> $${\rm P(AB)}=\frac{{}^{n}{\rm C}_3(n-3)!}{n!}=\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{6n(n-1)(n-2)}=\frac16$$

The most exciting thing is that you can obtain those without calculating anything but thinking intuitively.